# Azure AD B2C - Reject Injected HTML

Tags: javascript, html, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to customize my user flow pages in Azure AD B2C, however I want to bypass the injected HTML that is input between  tag and use my own fields. For example I want to use a custom input field for email and password when signing in. Is there a simple way to do this?

I have gone through the documentation but maybe I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. AAD B2C injects it’s fields into the div api.